# SwiftUI DatePicker issue iOS 17.1

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

The code below is working fine in **iOS 17.0.1**, but in the latest update, **17.1** DatePicker does not open when we tap on it.

After several tries, I found that on the long press, around 2-3 seconds, it opens the date picker.

Any solution for this issue? How do I open only on tap?

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){
Text("Date".localized())
    .applyFont(style: .Medium, size: 18)
    .foregroundColor(Colors.grayLight)
        HStack{
            let lastYear = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: Date()) ?? Date()
                if let date = checkLowerBound(){
                    DatePicker("",selection:$selectedDate, in: date...Date(), displayedComponents: [.date])
                        .frame(width: 100)
                    }else{
                    DatePicker("",selection:$selectedDate, in: lowestDate...Date(), displayedComponents: [.date])
                        .frame(width: 100)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                }
    .cardProperty()
    .allowsHitTesting(!(eventTransaction != nil && eventTransaction?.by != UserDefaults.userID))
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal reproducible code that produces your specific issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I took the default DatePicker; please check below code

DatePicker("",selection: $selectedDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: [.date]).frame(width: 100)

Comment: show the code you are using, not just one line of it. Your issue is probably due to other factors. Show some code that can be compiled and run to produce your issue. Then others can try to find a solution.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine same line same code is working fine in iOS 17.0.1 with normal tap and after I updated mobile OS to 17.1 normal tap stopped working and on long press same code opened DatePicker so this is the issue of latest OS.

Comment: Since you don't want to show your code that can be compiled and run to produce your issue, I can only suggest you comment out the 
`allowsHitTesting...`, then your custom modifiers (eg cardProperty), one by one to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I already shared full code, i edit my question where you can find full code which i use for DatePicker

Comment: Got the same issue on UIKit, any updates? Thanks. @HardikThakkar

Comment: No not get any solution. I will update here once I find any solution for the same, also don't know why I am getting minus votes on the real issue.

Comment: same issue? did you solve it?

Comment: Hi @MetinAtalay No still not get any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue and found a solution. In my case, the problem arose when I used `onTapGesture` on the entire `ZStack` containing my content and called `view.endEditing()`. This issue occurred in version 17.1 but not in earlier versions.

Comment: People who found this answer helpful, can you please tell me the exact solution?

Answer (score 23):

It appears that if a `TapGesture` is handles somewhere higher in the hierarchy, as of 17.1, the `DatePicker` with `displayedComponents: .date` will defer to it, and not trigger its own behavior.

`simultaneousGesture` does not appear to help. However, I found a hacky solution. By wrapping the `DatePicker` with its own TapGesture handler with a required Count, this buggy behavior will not be triggered as long as the count is not fulfilled.

Minimal viable triggering code with solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var date = Date()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        DatePicker(
            "Foo",
            selection: $date,
            displayedComponents: .date
        )
        .onTapGesture(count: 99, perform: {
            // overrides tap gesture to fix ios 17.1 bug
        })
    }
    .onTapGesture {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I already had a tap gesture for DatePicker. So I put my gesture next one after (count:99):  like    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({ })